# How to resend POST data when using WebView.goBack() method?

Tags: android, webview, web, httpclient

I am working on an application where we are providing user with the option to navigate back to the webpages user has previously viewed.

The problem arises when user navigates back to a page which contained POST data.

I don't know how to detect that the page loaded in the WebView had POST data so that app can prompt a confirm dialog, if he wants to resend the POST data or not.

I have seen this happening in android browsers [Native browser & Skyfire]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several days of research I created a workaround to get rid of this situation.

I set a flag when `WebView.goback()` is called.

In my `onProgressChanged()` method I check if the url being loaded matches with the url which should contain the POST DATA, then I call `WebView.reload()`, I set my flag to false and I also override the `onFormResubmission` method of the `WebViewClient` this way:

```
@Override
public void onFormResubmission (WebView view, Message dontResend,Message resend){
    resend.sendToTarget();
}
```

For more detailed information, visit: http://mytechead.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/resubmit-post-data-in-a-webview/