# Android webview form resubmission go back

Tags: android, android-webview

So problem is: I open `webview` url with form and when I press back, it goes back to the same page. I think it is related to form resubmission. What can I do? Maybe there is an override for form resubmission handling in `WebViewClient` or `WebChromeClient` that I am not aware of? I cannot just handle url manually, because in my case it would be close to impossible to handle each possible case.

Here is my `back` logic?

```
@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how it act in browser?

Comment: It asks about form resubmission.

Comment: seems browser know the history is a form submit, but web view not know it. i suggest to use ajax and control the url location in js, if you have the control of web pages.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I do not. This is banking page's web page.

Comment: you may take a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460720/how-to-resend-post-data-when-using-webview-goback-method)

Comment: You can detect the URL and take an action accordingly.

Comment: @Skynet so do some hack of keeping old url and then looking if url points to the same place, setting some flags, etc. instead of some elegant solution?

Comment: What kind of onBackPressed is that? The method onBackPressed in Activity class does not return a boolean

Comment: No its not a hack, check `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)` - read up on this and you will understand what I mean. If that does not fit your needs, you are better off doing this the `Native` way. Apps are not websites!

Comment: @MisterSmith Fragment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889152/is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-html-forms-into-android-while-using-webview you can find your answer here.