# How can I get data from php page (without json)?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have this site (http://www.usadebtclock.com/us-debt-clock-widget.php) and I want to get number from it (there's no JSON) to my android studio application using retrofit 2 and show this number in the text view. What converter factory should I use instead GsonConverterFactory? Or how can I get number from this page to my text view?

I tried to use `GsonConverterFactory.create()` for this, but it didn't make a response and showed a log from `onFailure` method

**This is `MainActivity.class` (with useless GsonConverterFactory):**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(DolgAPI.HOST)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
                                .create())
                        .build();

                DolgAPI apiService = retrofit.create(DolgAPI.class);

                Call<String> call = apiService.getDolg();

                call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        tv.setText(response.body());
                        Log.d("MyLog", "Got it!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("MyLog", "Error");
                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }
}
```

**This is Retrofit2 response API:**

```
public interface DolgAPI {

    String HOST = "http://www.usadebtclock.com";

    @GET("us-debt-clock-widget.php")
    Call<String> getDolg();

}
```

Comment: that is not a single number, it is an HTML page with Javascript running on it, which changes the value. You can't get that value without evaluating the javascript

Comment: You can use `WebView` if you want to display realtime data.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko how can I load this page and evaluate javascript to get value?

Comment: WebView seem the way to go, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889152/is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-html-forms-into-android-while-using-webview

Comment: using `WebView` is the simplest way I think. Also you may want to know that the value on the page is just a dummy, and is calculated by JavaScript only. It is not loaded from somewhere on the internet. So you can just make similar logic in your app.

Comment: You can check this link for more about [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview)

Comment: @PratikButani thank you, I used WebView and it's work!

Answer (score 0):

I used WebView to dispaly value from that site

It contains JavaScript so I used next lines to allow executing web scripts in application:

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all looks like the website if not functional as it not loading.
But if assume it is working and you don't have there any GET/ endpoint, you will receive back whole HTML document, and you need to parse it via html tags to fetch the required text.

Answer (score -1):

You should use ResponseBody

```
getDolg() should return Call<ResponseBody>
```

Then you have to parse html.
Loan returns in this format

```
<span id="debt-clock">$21,954,170,905,365.84</span>
```

You can parse html using regex.