# WebView - Is it possible to Override a method to get the value from form submission?

Tags: android, webview

After submitting a form to the server

Java

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="helloWorld" value="zzz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Assuming the server returns the text HTTP 200 and payload `qwerty`, how do I make the `WebView` process this return value in Java without using JavaScript from the webpage to call the application?

Comment: you can inject `javascript` which will intersect that data, and return it to your JavascriptInterface, as Tito Leiva wrote below

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a webview, it's necessary the implementation of a `WebviewAppInterface`. I'm not sure if is possible without Javascript. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889152/is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-html-forms-into-android-while-using-webview) and the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview).