# How to handle navigation with WebViews in same app of Android

Tags: android, webview

Greeting to all,

I'm a beginner at Android development and need your help.
I want to use WebView in app and navigate a specific native page from WebView in the same app.
It means this flow.

Top Page(Native) --> Page1 (WebView) --> Second Page(Native)

I can show Page1 (WebView) in emulator of Android (pixel3a).
But I still can't do the navigation to the Second Page.

Please tell me a good way.

Comment: You may get your answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889152/is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-html-forms-into-android-while-using-webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889152/is-it-possible-to-get-data-from-html-forms-into-android-while-using-webview)

Comment: Do you want to navigate from WebView to Second page via link tap or somehow else? Also it depends on what type of the 'pages' you have - activities or fragments or both.

Comment: Check this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview)

Comment: Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305089/how-to-load-external-webpage-inside-webview). This will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks your post, Artem Chernousov. It is via link in WebView. I can not move link in WebView to Second Page(Native) by click the link.